# Standard error of log relative risk in spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

My objective is to present the variation for a spatial relative risk. The `relrisk` function in the `spatstat` package has the option to compute the standard error of relative risk with the `se` argument. Relative risks are commonly expressed logarithmically and while the `estimate` from the `relrisk` function output can be transformed, the `SE` cannot.

For example, for a relative risk:

```
f1 <- spatstat::relrisk(spatstat.data::chorley, relative = TRUE, se = TRUE)
plot(f1$estimate); plot(f1$SE)
```

But, for a log relative risk, the standard errors cannot be transformed in a similar manner as the relative risk estimate.

```
plot(log(f1$estimate))
```

Can someone suggest a computational solution? Or would it be possible to add this feature to the `relrisk` function, perhaps as a logical argument `log` to estimate log relative risk and its standard error? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the delta method, the standard error of `log(R)` is approximately `se(R)/R`, that is, the standard error of `R` divided by the estimate of `R`. So the quickest solution is

```
plot(with(f1, se/estimate))
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks, @Adrian!